# Lying for shalom bayis only?

Tags: halacha, shalom-peace

We learn in the [Torah](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0118.htm) that Hashem lied to Avraham about what Sarah said. Rashi [says](http://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.18.13.2?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) that Hashem changed the truth when telling it over to Avraham for the sake of peace. From episode we learn that just as G-d lied for the sake of peace, we can as well.

Is this only regarding peace with one's spouse? or does this apply to other interpersonal relationships eg. Parents, friends, co-workers, children. Are there any sources which discuss this?

Comment: see last halacha in chafetz chaim hilchot lashon hara

Answer (score 4):

No, It applies to all interpersonal relationships. See Yevamos 65b where the statement of the other shvatim to Yosef is under discussion.

See also Magen Avraham in siman 156 in the name of seffer chassidim #426. And look in Rabbi Margolios' footnotes there for more maareh mikomos.

Comment: is it possible to quote any of these mekoros? would love to see them inside, right now i dont have any of those seforim

Comment: (R. Ilai): It is permitted to deviate (from truth) for the sake of Shalom - "Your father commanded ... tell Yosef to bear the sin (of his brothers)".
1.(R. Noson): This is a Mitzvah - "And Shmuel said ... Sha'ul will hear (that I am going to anoint David) and he will kill me" (so Hash-m told him to say a falsehood).
(h)(Tana d'Vei R. Yishmael - Beraisa): Shalom is so great that even Hash-m deviated (for its sake). Sarah said "And my husband is old"; Hash-m told Avraham only that she said, "And I am old". (Yevamos 65b from dafyomi.co.il)

Comment: He writes to look in seffer chassidim 1061 and his footnotes there, one of which references his work printed at the end of the book called chasdei olam. Shu't chassam soffer 6 59, hagahos maharsham in Orach chaim 156 and divrei shaul in agados on yevamos there.

Comment: The standard seffer chassidim found in most Yeshivos has his footnotes.